# Get Projection Matrix from OpenGL in version 3.3

Tags: opengl, freeglut

For compatibility reasons I have to mix old and modern OpenGL code. I would like to retrieve the current projection- and modelview-matrix from OpenGL to pass it to the shader by using a uniform-variable.

The following code shows my attempt to do that for the projection-matrix only. It does *not* work as intended:

```
float m[16];
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(60, aspect, 0.01f, 2.0f);
glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, m);
```

After these lines Matrix `m` contains the identity. I checked this using the following code:

```
printf("%f %f %f %f\n", m[0], m[4], m[8],  m[12]);
printf("%f %f %f %f\n", m[1], m[5], m[9],  m[13]);
printf("%f %f %f %f\n", m[2], m[6], m[10], m[14]);
printf("%f %f %f %f\n", m[3], m[7], m[11], m[15]);
```

I created the context using [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) and explicitly requested an OpenGL 3.3 context using the following code:

```
...
glutInitContextVersion(3, 3);
glutCreateWindow(title);
```

When I change the version to OpenGL 2.0 the code above works as expected. Every version above produces the described problem.

I'm working on Xubuntu using an *Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics*.

**Can someone explain this behaviour? Can someone offer a solution?**

Comment: Is Mesa [actually giving you](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Get_Context_Info) a Compatibility context when you ask for 3.3 without specifying `glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE)`?  Or is it silently upgrading it to Core?  What does `glGetError()` return before/after the `glGetFloatv()` call?

Comment: Why is every OpenGL question on StackOverflow being downvoted..? This is a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: I checked the version after the context is created (thanks for the link). `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` returns *Version: 4.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 12.1.0-devel (git-8c3ecde 2016-06-08 xenial-oibaf-ppa)* and `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAJOR_VERSION/GL_MINOR_VERSION, ...)` tells me the same. Why do I get a different version, when I explicitly request a 3.3 Context?
The core context explains the behaviour. I added an error callback using `ARB_debug_output` and `glMatrixMode` is of course the first function that is reported as deprecated.

Comment: When I request a *compatibility* context I get the following error when calling `glutCreateWindow`:
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadFBConfig
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  34 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  36
  Current serial number in output stream:  35

Answer (score 2):

The >=OpenGL-3.3 compatibility profiles are an optional feature and there's no requirement to actually support it. Most OpenGL implementations actually don't support the compatibility profiles. The notable exceptions are the proprietary drivers of NVidia and AMD. Hence mixing OpenGL-3.3 with legacy stuff will not work reliably for all systems.

But why are you doing that

> ```
> float m[16];
> glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
> glLoadIdentity();
> gluPerspective(60, aspect, 0.01f, 2.0f);
> glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, m);
> ```

… at all? First and foremost GLU is not part of OpenGL and GLU functions are just little helpers that internally call OpenGL functions. Anyway the gluPerspective function is extremely simple and the roundtrip through OpenGL just to get the matrix well is awkward (and to be honest is triggering my gag reflex).

At its core gluPerspective is determining parameters for glFrustum:

```
void gluPerspective(
    double fov,
    double aspect,
    double znear, float zfar)
{
    double const height = znear * tanf(fovyInDegrees * M_PI / 360.0);
    double const width = height * aspect;
    glFrustum(-width, width, -height, height, znear, zfar);
}
```

That's all it does. glFrustum itself is very simple as well.

```
void glFrustum(double l, double r, double b, double t, double n, double f)
{
    double M[4][4];
    M[0][0] = 2.f*n/(r-l);
    M[0][1] = M[0][2] = M[0][3] = 0.f;

    M[1][1] = 2.*n/(t-b);
    M[1][0] = M[1][2] = M[1][3] = 0.f;

    M[2][0] = (r+l)/(r-l);
    M[2][1] = (t+b)/(t-b);
    M[2][2] = -(f+n)/(f-n);
    M[2][3] = -1.f;

    M[3][2] = -2.f*(f*n)/(f-n);
    M[3][0] = M[3][1] = M[3][3] = 0.f;
    glMultMatrixd(&M[0][0]);
}
```

It's trivial to rewrite this to take a pointer to a matrix as a parameter which you then can directly pass to a uniform.

Comment: Thanks for the honest answer. The gag reflex is present here, too. You're right, it's obviously easy to rewrite gluPerspective or other projection matrices. My question was a bit misleading, because my main goal is to do this for the modelview-matrix. This would prevent me from rewriting large parts of the code that uses the matrix stack and the glRotate, glScale and glTranslate functions. The best solution would be to use a proper math library like glm